# view / edit httpd.conf centos

Tags: centos

i'm runnin 32 bit centos 5.5

how can i view / edit

httpd.conf

from ssh?

Like what command.

Thanks

Answer (score 2):

You need to use a text editor like nano or vi. So for example it would be vi httpd.conf and then press enter.

Comment: I love that you suggested `vi` ;)